# bonsai-elasticsearch-rails - cannot require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, elasticsearch, heroku-toolbelt, bonsai-elasticsearch

When I run:

```
$ heroku run bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Artist' FORCE=true
```

the response in the terminal is:

```
Running bundle exec rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS=Artist FORCE=true on doremi... up, run.3015
Starting up a new ElasticSearch client with https://hexcode.bonsai.io
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Elasticsearch
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bonsai-elasticsearch-rails-0.0.4/lib/bonsai/elasticsearch/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The error appears to originate from this require statement in `lib/tasks/elasticsearch.rake`

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import'
```

I have checked that all my `elastic-*` gems are their most up to date versions: 0.1.7 for elasticsearch-rails and elasticsearch-model, 0.0.4 for bonsai-elasticsearch-rails, however I did notice here https://rubygems.org/gems/bonsai-elasticsearch-rails that bonsai-elastic-search rails depends on bundler 1.5 and Heroku is using 1.9.7 which is not possible to change as far as I can see. Could this be the crux of the matter?

I also have a similar error in my logs when I try to deploy

```
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  NameError: uninitialized constant Elasticsearch 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  rake aborted! 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bonsai-elasticsearch-rails-0.0.4/lib/bonsai/elasticsearch/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/Rakefile:4:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  LoadError: cannot load such file -- bonsai-elasticsearch-rails 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/Rakefile:4:in `require' 
Oct 09 17:04:27 doremi app/worker.1:  /app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rails/bundler requires the gems in the order they’re declared in the gemfile. This error occurred because I was declaring `bonsai-elasticsearch-rails` above `elasticsearch-rails` and `elasticsearch-model`. It was therefore resolved by declaring `bonsai-elasticsearch-rails` underneath the other two.